# Error: Unsupported image type discord.js v14

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Making the bot which sends a greeting image for new user, I noticed,that it doesn`t shows error for the user without an avatar, and it shows error in the title for user with his own avatar.
I am getting user avatar for this greeting image this way:

```js
const avatarURL = member.user.displayAvatarURL({format: "png", forceStatic: true, size: av.size});
```

When I tried to `console.log(avatarURL)` it shows, that every user has got an avatar with .webp, which is not supported in canvas.
How to solve this problem?

Comment: Try using a conversion library to convert the image type

Answer (score 0):

You are using the method incorrectly. There is no `format`. It is `extension`.

Comment: Thank you,
displayAvatarURL({ extension: 'png' })
works for me